# condition before sign up in Devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Devise for my users in my rails app.

In my user model i have column **randomID**, this column is uquinesse for each user
and i generate it when the user sign-up

In the user model i have also **addBY**, i use that because the user need the **randomID** of another user for sign-up

So i will have tree relation between all users

all works fine, but my brobleme now is if the user enter the wrong **randomID**,
i must check if exist in my DATABASE or not

if the value exist i let the user sign-up

else i display a message error

any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call a function to check for a value existence before your `create` action.

in your users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_for_token, only: :create

  ...

  private

  def check_for_token
    redirect_to root_path unless User.exists?(:randomID => params[:addBY])
  end
end
```

Comment: thnx it works ! just i need to add a notice, i did this ( redirect_to root_path , notice: "error message!!" unless User.exists?(:randomID => params[:addBY]) ) but the message doesn't not display !!